# Where is "by" declared in the protractor source?

Tags: javascript, protractor

In the following code snippet:

```
element(by.id('myDiv'));
```

The `element` is declared in line 740 in [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L740) source. But I couldn't identify where is `by` declared. Where is this variable declared? If this is not declared anywhere, how does this variable get resolved?

Reading the source, `by` is the "locator" and [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/locators.js) source maybe related to it. But I couldn't see from that source any declaration of `by` variable.

Comment: I guess here https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js#L36. And somewhere someone does `var by = require(...).By`.

Comment: +1. And where is that source might be?

Comment: You should look in the code where `element(by.id('myDiv'));` is.

Comment: That's just an example code I keep seeing as example and they use it as if it was already declared somewhere.

Comment: I guess I found it. It's here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-protractor/angular-protractor.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by` is defined by [webdriver.js](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) and extended in protractor with specific angular locators like  `by.model`.

Locators in webdriver.js are defined in [this file](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/webdriver/locators.js).

The extension in protractor is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/locators.js#L20).